# How do I read Cygwin's `/bin/kill` man page without bash's `kill` builtin interfering?

Tags: windows, kill, man, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin on Windows 10 but I also use Ubuntu with WSL2. I can't reproduce this with the latter. When I type `man kill` in cygwin, it says `No manual entry for kill`. When I type `man /bin/kill`, it appears to show the right file, but it's sandwiched between binary gibberish:

[image]

How do I run `man` to properly view this page?

Comment: When man tells you there's no manpage for something, it means it can find no manpage period, whether it be for  built-in, executable, system call, C library call, file format or anything else. `man /some/path` is just telling man to literally read the file at that path as a manpage, so it's trying to parse the kill executable as a manpage (showing you whatever strings it can find in it, including the text for help/usage that you see). You just don't have the corresponding manpage installed at all (or not in a location searched by man, anyway).

Comment: @muru ah, okay that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: And you can still use `/bin/kill --help` for command options

Comment: @admstg Yeah, I noticed that but it didn't give the information I was looking for. I'm not sure if the man page would either, to be honest. I'm trying to figure out how to "kill" a running Windows service from the cygwin cli. `/bin/kill -f -W <windows_service_pid>` gave an error message even though `<windows_process_id>` worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no man pages

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/kill
cygwin-3.5.1-1
```

so the program belongs to the cygwin package.

```
$ cygcheck -l cygwin |grep kill
/usr/bin/kill.exe
```

and there is no man pages.
But you can ask directly the program help

```
$ /usr/bin/kill --help
Usage: kill [-fW] [-signal] [-s signal] pid1 [pid2 ...]
       kill -l [signal] | -L

Send signals to processes

 -f, --force     force, using win32 interface if necessary
 -l, --list      print a list of signal names
 -L, --table     print a formatted table of signal names
 -s, --signal    send signal (use kill --list for a list)
 -W, --winpid    specified pids are windows PIDs, not Cygwin PIDs
                 (use with extreme caution!)
 -h, --help      output usage information and exit
 -V, --version   output version information and exit
```